# Can QGIS2 refresh layers without the need to reclassify each layer individually?

Tags: qgis, layers, csv

I have a set of layers which I'd like to have refreshed each time I open QGIS2.2.0 (Windows 7).  Each of 14 layers (polygons) is linked via a join to a csv file with no geometry. The layer displays a graduated fill based on data in the csv file. The CSV file is in the layer tree as well. The original csv file is update daily (using an R script).  So my procedure is to run the R script which updates the csv file, then open QGIS.  The csv files in qgis are in fact updated - i can see the new data in the attribute table, but the layer's gradient fill is  not updated, and I have to go through each layer properties and reclassify to see the new data displayed.

I thought there might be a setting, but I can't find one.  Or perhaps there is a better way to organise this project - maybe a database would be a better option, but I'm not clear how to set this up so I can retain the same level of automation.  Thanks for you help!